# How to Create Separate Folder in iOS swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

I am implementing an native iOS app. I am capturing images and videos by using the custom camera and stored into Photos in iPhone but I need to save in seperate single  folder for images and videos. And also I need to set a password for that folder through my App.Can anyone guide me for do this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var paths: [Any] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
let docDirectory: String = paths[0] as? String ?? ""
    // Get documents folder
let dataPath: String = URL(fileURLWithPath: docDirectory).appendingPathComponent("/yourFolder").absoluteString
if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dataPath) {
       try? FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: dataPath, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
  }
```